# The coset of the kernel is the kernel of the induced homomorphism

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$, $K$ be groups. Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$, and $q: G \rightarrow G/N$ be the canonical quotient homomorphism. Let $e:G \rightarrow K$ be a homomorphism whose kernel contains N. Then $e$ factors through a unique homomorphism $e':G/N \rightarrow K$ by the universal property of quotient groups.

By direct computation I've noticed that $Ker(e')=Ker(e)/N$. Should this be obvious from a more general fact (say, universal property, or one of the Isomorphism Theorems)? It looks like one might be able to give a one-line proof of this using the Third or Fourth Isomorphism Theorem, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

That's in the data of the situation: $e'(gN)=e(g)$ by definition, so 
$$gN\in\ker e'\iff g\in \ker e,$$
which implies $\ker e'=(\ker e)/N$, and by the *3rd isomorphism theorem*, we have
$$ \operatorname{coker} e' = (G/N)\!\!\Bigm/\!\! (\ker e/N) \simeq G/\ker e=\operatorname{coker} e.$$

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I got to $ker(e′)=ker(e)/N$ pretty much the way you did. I'm not too familiar with cokernels; may I ask what is their significance here?

Why is $G/ker(e)$ equal to $coker(e)$ rather than the coimage?

Comment: Basically, it's a way to decompose a morphism as a surjective morphism, followed by an injective morphism. Same as with the rings $\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z$. Likewise there is an image (which is isomorphic to the cokernel), as you know, and a coimage which is a measure of how far from being surjective a morphism is, just like the cokernel is a measure of how far from being injective it is.